# Remove only Cancel button from pFileUpload

Tags: angular, file-upload, primeng

When implementing `pFileUpload`, I get all 3 buttons but I do not need Cancel button.

As per the documentation, there is an attribute `showCancelButton` but when I apply there is no change.

```
<p-fileUpload name="demo[]" url="" mode="advanced" accept=".xml" 
maxFileSize="1000000" chooseLabel="Select File..." uploadLabel="Upload File" 
showCancelButton="false" >
</p-fileUpload>
```

Comment: and when using auto,whether keeping its value true/false/auto, only choose file shows up but i want choose and upload button and both enabled... please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `showCancelButton="false"` with `[showCancelButton]="false"`.

**Edit**

`showCancelButton` is not available in [2.0.6](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/2.0.6/components/fileupload/fileupload.ts) and you should upgrade to at least [4.1.0](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/4.1.0/src/app/components/fileupload/fileupload.ts)

If you cannot upgrade, then try this :

```
::ng-deep .ui-fileupload-buttonbar button:nth-child(3) {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: when i enclose it into brackets, app doesnt load up and throws error in console "Can't bind to 'showCancelButton' since it isn't a known property of 'p-fileUpload'."

Comment: Which version of PrimeNG do you use ?

Comment: 2.0.6 shows in package.json file. Is there a command to check ?

Comment: I also need help in adding radio button inside the template of pFileUpload, so how can i do that ? Help appreciated. Thanks